# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: users

Here is my code:

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    $variables['user_profile'] = menu_get_object('user');
}
```

I print the field "name" using `print $user_profile->name`, and I get the following error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 71 of SITE\sites\all\themes\parce\block--block--2.tpl.php).

I assumed `$user_profile` was not an object and I tried `print render($user_profile['name'])`, which returned me:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass

What is going on? I checked the Drupal API reference, and `menu_get_object()` should return me an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't print line numbers of the second error so I don't know if they happen on then same line. Maybe your notice is from something else.

What you could try is to print out the variable using `print_r`, `vardump`, `debug` or use the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module which creates some wrapper functions like `dpm` to print variables with Krumo.

It should be impossible that the same variable is an object and isn't an object at the same time. But it's hard to say more with the info you provided.

**Update:**
From your comments, I can see why you are getting the errors:

```
print $user_profile->field_country['und']['0']['value'];
```

Error >> Notice: Undefined index: **und** ...

```
print $user_profile['field_country']['und']['0']['value'];
```

Fatal >> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

The problem as I marked in the error message is that `und` is not defined in the field value. So `$user_profile->field_country` is ok but `$user_profile->field_country['und']` is undefined. The reason could be that it doesn't have a value set or that the language for the field isn't undefined. You should like I suggested above, print out the variable to see what it contains.

Comment: Hi googletrop, thanks for the input, i try to reproduce it again with the line numbers:


`line 65 > print $user_profile ->field_country['und']['0']['value'];`

Error >>
Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 65 of E:\www\parce\sites\all\themes\parce\block--block--2.tpl.php).

Now with: 

 `line 65 > print $user_profile['field_country']['und']['0']['value'];`

Error >>
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in E:\www\parce\sites\all\themes\parce\block--block--2.tpl.php on line 65

Comment: As googletorp suggested, install devel.module and then just do dpm($user_profile); That will tell you the exact type of that variable and the content. Maybe you are not viewing a user/x page? You need to make sure to only display that information when you are on a site where menu_get_object('user') returns anything.

Comment: @silkAmin Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I need to make some more testing but that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

`menu_get_object('user')` returns you an object only for specific URLs; if the URL of page where the block is visible is http://example.com/node/1, then the function will not return you an object.

As reported in the documentation:

> `menu_get_object()` provides access to objects loaded by the current router item. For example, on the page node/%node, the router loads the %node object, and calling `menu_get_object()` will return that.

In your case, the page URL should match user/%user, such as in the case of http://example.com/user/1, http://example.com/user/1/shortcuts, http://example.com/user/1/devel.

The function could also not return an object when the block is being shown in a user profile page, and if there are problems loading the user object. In this case, the user profile page would not be correctly visualized too, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this can't be the case because even though `print $user_profile ->field_country['und']['0']['value']` give me an error when i am on the administration side of the site, the output is still correctly printed on the front end, in this instance i get the country name.

Comment: @silkAdmin It depends from the path of the page you are visiting; it's not a matter of back end versus front end. If the administration page is at admin/config/people/accounts, then `menu_get_object('user')` doesn't return at object.

Comment: @silkAdmin In your question you report that the error you get is because you use `print $user_profile->name`, where `$user_profile` contains the value returned in from `menu_get_object('user')`; in that case, the error you see can only be caused from the fact you don't get an object from the function, which can happens as I explained. If that is not the code you used, then you should update  your question.