# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  

Tags: 7, views, forms

I have created a module, and I am trying to use the following code:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {     
  if ($form_state['view']->name == 'album1') {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

The line that causes the error is the following one:

```
if ($form_state['view']->name == 'album1') {
```

The error I get is the following one:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in mymodule_form_alter() (line 15 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\mymodule\mymodule.module).

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5185/notice-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$form_state['view']` is not defined for all the forms, and it is not a value set by Drupal core modules. Before to access `$form_state['view']->name` you should verify `$form_state['view']` is defined, and it is an object (and not an array, for example).

Comment: but desired value i am getting from the variable..